# How to get content of Blob in Azure using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I met a problem when retrieving data from blob in Azure. My code is like follows:

```
static async Task Main()
        {   

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("*");
            BlobContainerClient containerClient =  blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("*");
      
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("*");
            var content = blobClient.DownloadContent();

            BinaryData data = new BinaryData(content);
            var blobContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + data);
}
```

But the result shows all the properties except the contents area:

```
{"Value":{"Details":{"BlobType":0,"ContentLength":66924,"ContentType":"application/octet-stream","ContentHash":"JwTlI7cLcG+FWuewCaRuaQ==","LastModified":"2021-04-10T00:18:36+00:00","Metadata":{},"ContentRange":null,"ETag":"\u00220x8D8FBB62F1EC10C\u0022","ContentEncoding":null,"CacheControl":null,"ContentDisposition":null,"ContentLanguage":null,"BlobSequenceNumber":0,"CopyCompletedOn":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00","CopyStatusDescription":null,"CopyId":null,"CopyProgress":null,"CopySource":null,"CopyStatus":0,"LeaseDuration":0,"LeaseState":0,"LeaseStatus":1,"AcceptRanges":"bytes","BlobCommittedBlockCount":0,"IsServerEncrypted":true,"EncryptionKeySha256":null,"EncryptionScope":null,"BlobContentHash":null,"TagCount":0,"VersionId":null,"IsSealed":false,"ObjectReplicationSourceProperties":null,"ObjectReplicationDestinationPolicyId":null,"LastAccessed":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00","ImmutabilityPolicy":{"ExpiresOn":null,"PolicyMode":null},"HasLegalHold":false},"Content":{}}}
```

So I change my code as follows:

```
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {   

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("*");
            BlobContainerClient containerClient =  blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("*");
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("*");  

            string localPath = "./data/tmp.datablock";
            blobClient.DownloadTo(localPath);
            
            string contents;
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("./data/tmp.datablock", Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                contents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
            string jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(contents, options);
            Dictionary<string, dynamic>? values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(contents);
            
            foreach(var pair in values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Value);
            }  
        }
    }
```

And it works.

I just do not know why my first way can not work. And is there any better way to get the content of blob?

Thank all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of [`BlobClient.Download`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadcontent?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-specialized-blobbaseclient-downloadcontent) method is response of type [`BlobDownloadResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobdownloadresult?view=azure-dotnet). To read the content of the blob, you will need to use the `Content` property there.

Please try the following code:

```
static async Task Main()
{   

    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("*");
    BlobContainerClient containerClient =  blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("*");

    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("*");
    var response = blobClient.DownloadContent();

    BinaryData data = response.Value.Content;
    var blobContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + data);
}
```

Comment: But it shows compile error: ```'Response<BlobDownloadResult>' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no accessible extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'Response<BlobDownloadResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ```

Comment: The version of SDK I am using is 6.0.300

Comment: Sorry, my bad! You would need to use Response.Value and then you should be able to access the Content. Edited my answer. Please give that a try.

Comment: I have another question: when I try to process the content which are key-value pairs into dictionary<string, dynamic>, it shows some error:```'Error converting value "{"systemId":"P0700055","sessionId":"ec322078-8934-441e-a090-9c43e255ccf7",...to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'`````` 
            var jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(blobContents, options);
            Dictionary<string, dynamic>? values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonString);```

Comment: Please ask a separate question for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72969324/how-to-parse-content-get-from-azure-blob-into-dictionarystring-dynamic-using