# How to parse content get from Azure Blob into Dictionary<string, dynamic> using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to get contents from blob in Azure which is key-value pairs and transfer them into Dictionary<String, dynamic>. But it falled.
My code is as follows:

```
static async Task Main()
        {   

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("#");
            BlobContainerClient containerClient =  blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("#");
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("#");  
            var response = blobClient.DownloadContent();
            
            var data = response.Value.Content;
            var blobContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
            var jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(blobContents, options);
            Dictionary<string, dynamic>? values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonString);
}
```

But it shows that :

```
unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "﻿{"key":"value","...} to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'. Path '', line 1, position 104484.
```

I want to know how to fix it.Thank you!

Comment: can you add a sample of the content of the blob? What do you want as the key for the dictionary?

Comment: ```"{"systemId":"P0700055","sessionId":"ec322078-8934-441e-a090-9c43e255ccf7","startDateTime":"2021-04-10T00:13:13.0008388+00:00","timeSpanSec":30,"span":"00:00:30","signals":[]}```

Comment: The string is like "key": value pair.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private async Task<string> GetBlob(BlobClient blobClient)
    {
        string file = string.Empty;
        MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(stream).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (stream != null)
                {

                    stream.WriteTo(fileStream);
                    fileStream.Position = 0;

                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
                    file = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }

            return file;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That works. But I am wondering why I can not parse the return value of getContent() into dictionary, which is string type.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, simply remove the following 2 lines of code:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
var jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(blobContents, options);
```

and replace the following line of code:

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic>? values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonString);
```

with

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic>? values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(blobContents);
```

So your code would be something like:

```
static async Task Main()
        {   

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("#");
            BlobContainerClient containerClient =  blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("#");
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("#");  
            var response = blobClient.DownloadContent();
            
            var data = response.Value.Content;
            var blobContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            
            Dictionary<string, dynamic>? values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(blobContents);
}
```

Comment: I changed my code according to yours but it keeps showing that ```Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0.```

Comment: Hmmm…that’s weird. I took your JSON and uploaded that as a blob in my storage account. I was able to successfully read that using the code. Please run your code in debug mode and see check the blob’s content.